# npm install fails when package-lock.json is present

Tags: json, node.js, npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

I have some strange issue regarding the `package-lock.json`.
We are using `npm 5.6` and node `8.9.2`.

We have some project with dependencies. The developers can install the deps and push the package-lock.json as recommended:

```
     ...
                    "dependencies": {
                        "source-map": {
                            "version": "0.6.1",
                            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/-/source-map-0.6.1.tgz",
                            "integrity": "sha1-dHIq8y6WFOnCh6jQu95IteLxomM=",
                            "dev": true
                        }
                    }
    ...
```

They are getting their dependencies from https://registry.npmjs.org/..
Now we have some jenkins which gets its dependencies from some artifactory which serves as 'proxy' to https://registry.npmjs.org.

The build fails 75% of the times on some error like:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nalInternal" : {
```

Even when I clean the cache before with `sudo npm clean cache --force` (or remove `.npm`)

The error occurs always on a different place.
Now when I remove the `package-lock.json` before starting the build it works well every time.

A new package-lock.json is generated. It contains not the registry urls but the artifactory urls (`https://artifactory/xxx`). I thought it could maybe have to do with it. so I replaced the current `package-lock.json` in git with the one from jenkins. I tried again but again the same error and issue, only deleting the package-lock.json seems to solve it but as I read it's not recommended to ignore this file.

What could be an issue?